# php-fpm error "no input file specified" with Docker

Tags: nginx, docker, php

I am trying to setup a docker container for php-fpm. But encountering this error when visiting the web directory configured on localhost. I have been stuck here for over 5 hours.
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:latest
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN yum -y update

RUN rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/epel-release.rpm; rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm

#RUN yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
RUN systemctl stop firewalld; systemctl disable firewalld

RUN yum -y install php56w php56w-opcache php56w-cli php56w-common php56w-devel php56w-fpm php56w-gd  php56w-mbstring  php56w-mcrypt php56w-pdo php56w-mysqlnd php56w-pecl-xdebug php56w-pecl-memcache

RUN sed -i "s/;date.timezone =.*/date.timezone = UTC/" /etc/php.ini && \
    sed -i "s/display_errors = Off/display_errors = stderr/" /etc/php.ini && \
    sed -i "s/upload_max_filesize = 2M/upload_max_filesize = 30M/" /etc/php.ini && \
    sed -i -e "s/;daemonize\s*=\s*yes/daemonize = no/g" /etc/php-fpm.conf && \
    sed -i '/^listen = /c listen = 9000' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf && \
    sed -i '/^listen.allowed_clients/c ;listen.allowed_clients =' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

RUN mkdir -p /home/www
VOLUME ["/home/www"]

EXPOSE 9000

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/php-fpm", "-F"]
```

Check by `docker ps`

```
aab4f8ce0fe8        jason/fpm:v1        "/usr/sbin/php-fpm -   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:9002->9000/tcp   fpm
```

The data volume does exist. check by `docker inspect`

```
"Volumes": {
        "/home/www": "/home/www"
    },
    "VolumesRW": {
        "/home/www": true
    }
"Ports": {
            "9000/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "9002"
                }
            ]
        }
```

localhost nginx website config:

```
listen 80;
server_name admin.local.lumen.com;
index index.php index.html index.htm ;
root  /home/www/lumenback/public_admin;
error_log /home/wwwlogs/lumenback_error.log;
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location ~ .*\.php?$
{
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9002;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        #include        fastcgi.conf;
}
```

Error logged by php-fpm:

```
[error] 5322#0: *3798 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.16.1.19, server: admin.local.lumen.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9002", host: "admin.local.lumen.com"
```

Many people online said the error is caused by `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME`. Seems it is not the reason in my case.

Comment: it seems this error is related to something wrong in SCRIPT_FILENAME, can you `docker exec -it aab4f8ce0fe8 echo $SCRIPT_FILENAME` and paste it?

Comment: @user2915097 It prints nothing. I think $SCRIPT_FILENAME is not an env variable

Comment: Have you tried include fastcgi_params first then set SCRIPT_FILENAME?

Comment: Maybe you should check permissions. Try to change all php files to world readable and try again

Comment: @xuhdev Thanks. I changed data volume to a different directory with permission 755 and put fastcgi_params before SCRIPT_FILENAME. Now it works. Then I changed fastcgi_params back, still works. I guess the reason is the incorrect permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have got an incorrect file permission -- the process in the container cannot read php files. You can either change the php files readable by the user running php-fpm in the container. Note that the user name in the container differs from the names on the host, so specifying user ID is probably a better way (or simply make them world readable).